# Язык программирования C

Tags: c

У меня щас встал вопрос про язык програмирова "C", он ещё актуален? Если я выучу я его то я не потеряю время (вдруг он обвалится лет так через 5)? Не осуждайте, мне просто интересно и я ещё новичёк в программировании.

Comment: На языке C написано примерно всё, ток что это будет чудо из чудес, если обвалится. Это во-первых

Comment: А во-вторых, за пять лет можно успеть с десяток разных языков на неплохом уровне изучить, зацикливаться на одном языке глупо

Comment: А учитывая, что думаю половина языков заимствовала основы синтаксиса из C, то и тут его знание окажется не лишним

Comment: На языке Си написан весь Linux. Пока не исчезнут сервера всё будет в порядке. Язык обладает свойством автомата, что вы напишете, то и произойдёт. Это даст очень хорошие навыки для программирования. Все другие языки обладают слишком затуманенным понятием, что команды делают. И популярным вопросом на данном сайте такой: *"А почему она делает не то?"*

Answer (score 2):

Язык Си актуален c 80х годов и актуален для написания драйверов, сложных библиотек, сетевых приложений, вычислительных кластеров, всяких движков и других языков программирования в 2020.

Для прикладного ПО актуален для программ на GTK, но сложное управление памятью не дает приемуществ перед другими языками.

Основное приемущество языка это скорость и максимальная компактность в памяти.

Если Вы хотите разрабатывать прикладное ПО - необходимость в Си прийдет лет через 10, когда Ваши приложения станут настолько сложными, что потребуют ускорения в некоторых местах.

Для простых приложений лучше начать с Python, C#, Java.

Если хочется быть ближе к железу, то С++ сочетает в себе управление памятью и любые функции голого Си. На нем же построены одни из лучших прикладных фреймворков Qt и MSVC.